# When I use For Each in UiPath, it shows "Option Strict On disallows late binding"

Tags: java, uipath, rpa, uipath-studio

[image: error image]

First, I call an API endpoint to get the response, and I convert the response to jsonResult by using Deserialize JSON.

jsonResult is an object, with fields such as "code", "status", "data".
jsonResult("data") is a user List.

Now I need to use these users' name one by one.
So I use For Each on the List: jsonResult("data"), the item in the List is named currentItem, then the username would be currentItem("name"), right?
But it shows error: Option Strict On disallows late binding.

But before the "For Each", if I print jsonResult("data")(0)("name"), there's no error at all.
And if I use "For Each" and then I print the currentItem directly instead of currentItem("name"), there's no error either.
How can I solve this issue? I need to use these users' name one by one for some activities.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty easy. You need to set the proper type.

1. Click `For Each`
2. Select `TypeArgument`
3. Make sure `JObject` is selected